# Tailwind underline hover animation

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I've spent a day figuring out how to make an animation after hovering over the link by using Tailwind-CSS.
Here is the animation I want mine link looks like the video.
[Sample from Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aswRKAjjWuE)

I have tried using `:after`, but it didn't work out.
Here is my link component => https://codepen.io/qqharry21/pen/xxPwqjQ

I Hope can learn how to fix it, and make it works like the video by Tailwind-CSS, thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can achieve that in pure tailwind with group max-w-{x} and transition-all, use group-hover on the span so when you pass over the link it start the animation

```
<a href="#" class="group text-sky-600 transition duration-300">
Link
<span class="block max-w-0 group-hover:max-w-full transition-all duration-500 h-0.5 bg-sky-600"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're not wanting to include a CSS file just for this functionality or you just want to do it in Tailwind - the code snippet I've posted below is based purely on Tailwind CSS.

```
<a class="group text-pink-500 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out" href="#">
  <span class="bg-left-bottom bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-500 to-pink-500 bg-[length:0%_2px] bg-no-repeat group-hover:bg-[length:100%_2px] transition-all duration-500 ease-out">
    This text gets 'underlined' on hover
  </span>
</a>
```

Cheers and happy coding!

Comment: this one is actually more right because its only underline on the text we want and not the full width

Answer (score 9):

You can you transition for that:

```css
    .link-underline {
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
        background-size: 0 3px;
        background-position: 0 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        transition: background-size .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .link-underline-black {
        background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(#F2C, #F2C)
    }

    .link-underline:hover {
        background-size: 100% 3px;
        background-position: 0 100%
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 py-6 flex flex-col justify-center sm:py-12">
    <div class="relative py-3 sm:max-w-xl sm:mx-auto">
        <a href="#" class="font-display max-w-sm text-2xl font-bold leading-tight">
            <span class="link link-underline link-underline-black text-black"> Link Hover Effect </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

You can do everything in one single line using the `after` pseudo-element:

```
<section class="bg-[#0077b6] h-screen w-screen text-white flex items-center justify-center">
  <a class="text-3xl relative after:bg-white after:absolute after:h-1 after:w-0 after:bottom-0 after:left-0 hover:after:w-full after:transition-all after:duration-300 cursor-pointer">Text you want to underline in just one line</a>
</section>
```

Here is a pen with a use case:

https://codepen.io/Marcos-Riverola/pen/poQmRKV?editors=1010

Comment: Concise and effective! 
Best answer